# How to use dynamic mimeTypes in Google drive export files API in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am using google drive get files and export files nodejs API, But in this API there are lots of mimeType, if I upload daily used files like .docx, .xls, pdf, etc. then I can handle, but If the file mimeType is different then how can I handle those types. And its very tricky to create lots of conditions in my code for handling mimeTypes.
Please help me on this.Following is my code.

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
var fileId = fileId;
var ext, mimTypes;

drive.files.get({fileId: fileId},function(err, res){

if(res.data.mimeType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'){
   mimTypes = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text';
   ext = '.docx';
}else if(res.data.mimeType =='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'){
   mimTypes = 'text/csv';
   ext = '.xls';
}else if(res.data.mimeType == 'application/pdf'){
 if(res.data.name.indexOf(".pdf") != -1){
   res.data.name = res.data.name.split('.pdf')[0];
 }
   mimTypes = 'application/pdf';
   ext = '.pdf';
}
```

For export file from google drive:

```
var dest = config.lib.fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/'+res.data.name+ext);
drive.files.export({fileId: res.data.id, mimeType: mimTypes}, {responseType: 'stream'},
function(err, res){
  res.data
  .on('progress', function (state) {
      console.log('progress', state);
      io.sockets.emit("upload_progress", state);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
      console.log('Done');
      io.sockets.emit("upload_progress", {percent: 100});
  })
  .on('error', err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
  })
  .pipe(dest);
})
```

Comment: How else do you expect to do it without making extra conditions?

Comment: Actually I want to use this API with the minimum conditions, If I have 100 file types(Different mimeType) then it will adding more conditions in my code.

Comment: Thats not going to happen.  There is no way your code can guess what the mimetype is unless you add it.   Start adding the file types or stop supporting them all.

Comment: Ohh ok. thanks for your answer.